# What is the fewest number of shirts she could order?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> Suppose that the probability of a random student answering the "Math Challenge of the Day" question at Riverdale High School is $10 \%$. For each of $100$ days, the teacher randomly selects one student who will try and answer the problem. The prize for winning the contest is an "I solved the problem of the day" T-shirt. Suppose the teacher wants to place an order of shirts at the beginning of the $100$-day term and be at least $95 \%$ certain she will have enough shirts. What is the fewest number of shirts she could order?

The expected number of students to solve the problems is $\dfrac{1}{10} \cdot 100 = 10$. How do we be "at least $95 \%$ certain she will have enough shirts"?

Comment: Sounds like a "standard" statistics/probability problem to me

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial distribution, calculate the probability that $0$ students answer correctly, then $1$, then $2$ and so on.  Add them up until you reach $0.95$.  You might get away with the normal approximation, but the numbers seem a bit small.

Answer (score 0):

We can approximate the distribution by the normal distribution $N(10,3)$ and so the fewest number of shirts needed to be at least $95 \%$ sure of having enough shirts is $10+2(3) = 16$.